# Where to put database files when deploying file-based database app?

Tags: database, windows, deployment

If you are deploying an app which uses a file-based database such as SQLite or Access-MDB, where should the database files be deployed to on a machine, bearing in mind that the app will need full access to this location?

Don't MS guidelines say that the `%PROGRAMFILES%` folder should only contain read-only application files?

Where should database files be placed?  In the `%APPDATA%` folder?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should **not** be using the `Program Files` directory anymore to store dynamic information.

This Windows Blog [User Account Control Data Redirection](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx) gives a nice summary:

> Ensure that you do not hard-code paths once you have determined the appropriate locations. Instead, use one of the following programming models and APIs to retrieve the correct paths of specific Windows known folders:
>
> C/C++ native applications: Use the SHGetKnownFolderPath function that retrieves the full path of a known folder identified by the folder's KNOWNFOLDERID, a GUID parameter indicating the known location you would like to obtain:
>
> - FOLDERID_ProgramData – Shared program data directory for all users
> - FOLDERID_LocalAppData – Per-user program data directory (non-roaming)
> - FOLDERID_RoamingAppData – Per-user program data directory (roaming)
>
> Managed Code: Use the System.Environment.GetFolderPath function. GetFolderPath takes a parameter indicating the Known Location you would like to obtain:
>
> - Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData – Shared program data directory for all users
> - Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData – Per-user program data directory (non-roaming)
> - Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData – Per-user program data directory (roaming)
>
> If none of the above-mentioned options are available, use the environment variable:
>
> - %ALLUSERSPROFILE% – Shared program data directory for all users
> - %LOCALAPPDATA% – Per-user program data directory (non-roaming) - Windows Vista or later
> - %APPDATA% – Per-user program data directory (roaming) - Windows Vista or later